# ASP.NET Image Listbox

Tags: asp.net, image, combobox, listbox, obout

I want to display a list of images (instead of text) for the user to choose from. The control is databound (the URLs come from the database) Instead of the typical vertical scroll bar in a listbox, I want this box to be horizontal. I'm looking for an ASP.NET server control similar to this: http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet/webimageviewer.aspx#Overview

I considered all the answers and finally decided to use the ComboBox from obout.com which can also display the images.

thanks
Shankar

Answer (score 1):

if you are experienced with ajax and/or jQuery you can have a look at the jQuery SliderGallery control.

http://ui.jquery.com/repository/real-world/product-slider/

Answer (score 0):

I'd just put them in a div (asp:panel?) that's styled to have a particular height and width and overflow horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, this seems like a pretty simple problem to me.  Just create a [scrollable DIV](http://www.divitodesign.com/2007/12/css-how-to-use-overflow/) that will host all the images.

Comment: I used AjaxControlToolkit SlideShow control, but could not get the selected index on post back. I also tried one from obout.com, same problem. May be these controls are meant for just displaying the images (and not used as a form field in post back). Both useless for my purpose.